# usage of where in a sentence

Tags: where

I am not pretty sure how I could use *where* in this case:

> In this video, you will see where are the favorite places for the zander to hide and where is it floundering during the day and at night.

If I use it like this the sentence becomes awkward:

> In this video, you will see where the favorite places for the zander to hide are and where it is floundering during the day and at night.

Thank you!

Comment: The second sentence sounds more correct. "Where are" and "where is" sound like you asking questions not making statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence is correct. As mentioned in the comment, "where are" and "where is" are usually used to introduce questions, not statements.

It probably sounds awkward to you because "where" and "are" are separated by so many words that you've lost track of the reference. You can solve that by rewording it to remove the "where ... are" phrase entirely, e.g.

> In this video, you will see the zander's favorite places to hide and where it is floundering during the day and at night.

"where it is" doesn't suffer from the same awkwardness because there's only one word separating them.